# React typescript useContext not triggering re-render on change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context

I am trying to change object using useContext but it is not triggering. object does not change on the screen. If I click another button, it triggers both of them. The code is as seen in the below code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vpr9msmaicih7-lnkzr

*Provider

```
    import React, { FC, useState, createContext, ReactNode } from "react";
    import { Data } from "./type";
    type ContextType = {
      text: string;
      setText: (text: string) => void;
      data: Data | undefined;
      setData: (data: Data) => void;
    };
    type Props = {
      children: ReactNode;
    };
    const AuthContext = createContext<ContextType>({} as ContextType);
    
    const AuthProvider: FC<Props> = ({ children }: Props) => {
      const [text, setText] = useState<string>("default");
      const [data, setData] = useState<Data | undefined>({} as Data);
      const value = {
        text,
        setText,
        data,
        setData
      };
      return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
    };
    export { AuthProvider, AuthContext };
```

*Page

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          if (data) {
            let obj = data;
            obj.id = "1001";
            obj.date = new Date().toString();
            setData(obj);
          }
        }}
      >
        Change Object Not working
      </button>
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Page />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

```
export interface Data {
  id: string;
  date: string;
}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.
Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're actually altering the state directly when you say `let obj = data`.  `obj` is now just a reference to `data`.  Then when you set `setData(obj)`, react doesn't know that the state variable has changed, because you already changed it.  What you're probably looking to do is make a copy.  You can use the spread operator `{...data}` to do that. Then use `setData`:

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    if (data) {
      let obj = {...data};
      obj.id = "1001";
      obj.date = new Date().toString();
      setData(obj);
    }
  }}
>
  Change Object Not working
</button>
```